# getting null values from editext in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I got a problem with edit text...here i will explain regarding my problem

1. I declared a fragment in fragmentactivity.
2. In that fragment i have an edittext.
3. I have a button in fragmnetactivity.
4. If i click on that button I need to get values from that edittext which is in fragment.
5. So fro this I declared that edittext globally.
6. And It asked me to declare with "static".
7. Until this it is fine but while getting values it was giving null values.
8. I think the problem is occurred by declaring it as static.

I tried with all other ways but didn't found good solution.
Can i know what the fault i have done with...
Hope I have given required details to clear my question.If you feel it as insufficient  please let me know it..

In fragment....
     edt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.note);

In fragmentactivity

```
static EditText edt;
static String a;
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        a = edt.getText().toString();
        Log.v("a",""+a);
}
});
```

Comment: post your code what you have tried

Comment: Can you show your code? If you defined the EditText globally, there is no need to make it static, so probably you have an EditText with the same name defined

Comment: post your code. without looking at the code only God can answer we are human.

Comment: Plz provide some code.

Comment: ya i have posted required code...is ther any need to post much code

Comment: hi did anybody get what the problem is

Comment: hi blackbelt..how r u....thanx for showing interest in my question but the wrong is while declaring edt as static i got another solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a good solution for this....in android if you declare editext in fragment and to get values in activity it will give null values but the best part of android is if you dont get it in plan A it will show remaing 25 alphabets...So you have to implement it in anothe manner
I will sugest you one implementation
remove static from the edittext and keep it in fragment...

```
edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Editable b=s;
                a=b.toString();//use this a where ever you want in activity


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined EditText. But did you initialized it by calling findViewById or something?

or did you defined it twice?

Comment: yaa actually my fragmentactivity consists of a fragment this fragment consists of edittext so i called it by using findviewbyid

Comment: If you declared that global static, then no need to declare another variable her. just call it as Classname.textname.getText()...

Comment: Also, try to declare and define in the same class.

Comment: thankyou fr showing intrest in my problem...but this didnt worked for me...but thanq soo much